# Search by User that Created the Contact

Tags: search

I would like to create a group of contacts added by a particular admin.  How can I search for contacts added by x contact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Advanced Search you can use the Change Log to enter the Admin's name in the  'added by' section and set it to 'Added'.

You have to put in the contact's "Sort Name" in the box for this to work (as of 5.7, at least) [citing Alan Dixon's comment from below].

Then you should be able to make a Smart Group from this.

Comment: Thanks @petednz!  This works for us for now.  My one complaint about this method is that there really should be a way to use unique ids, e-mail addresses, etc other than just the contacts name - we are a large organization and could have a few people with the same name!

Comment: Complaints are best dealt with by finding a way to contribute to a fix ;-) Open Source and 'all that'. If you can't sort this yourself, there will be Partners or other devs who could take a whack at this if you have some funding available

Comment: I know :) maybe complaint wasn't the right word, more like, something I'd like to see.

Comment: fair enough to critique how things are :-)

Comment: I notice that you have to put in the contact's "Sort Name" in the box for this to work (as of 5.7, at least).

Comment: thx - updated answer to make it more useful to others